# Oracle 10g aggregating from two different rows and columns into a single row

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I'm having a table containing employment start and end date as follow:

```
EEID | EMP_START_DATE | EMP_TERM_DATE 
-----+----------------+---------------
1    | 2014-01-01     | null
1    | null           | 2014-03-30
1    | 2014-06-01     | null
1    | null           | 2014-12-31
1    | 2015-08-01     | null
2    | 2001-07-01     | null
3    | 2010-03-01     | null
3    | null           | 2010-03-30
3    | 2010-04-01     | null
3    | null           | 2010-04-30
```

I would like to transform it as follow, sorted by employeeId (EEID) and employment period(s):

```
EEID | EMP_START_DATE | EMP_TERM_DATE  
-----+----------------+---------------
1    | 2014-01-01     | 2014-03-30
1    | 2014-06-01     | 2014-12-31
1    | 2015-08-01     | null
2    | 2001-07-01     | null
3    | 2010-03-01     | 2010-03-30
3    | 2010-04-01     | 2010-04-30
```

**Question**

Can someone tell me how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation.  This requires enumerating the starts and ends and then using this enumeration for aggregation:

```
select eeid, max(emp_start_date) as emp_start_date,
       max(emp_end_date) as emp_end_date
from (select t.*,
             (case when emp_start_date is not null
                   then count(emp_start_date) over (partition by eeid order by emp_start_date)
                   else count(emp_end_date) over (partition by eeid order by emp_send_date)
              end) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by eeid, seqnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lead and lag to get previous/next date values when they are null for the current row:

```
select eeid,
  emp_start_date as orig_start_date,
  emp_term_date as orig_term_date,
  coalesce(emp_start_date,
    lag(emp_start_date)
      over (partition by eeid order by coalesce(emp_start_date, emp_term_date)))
    as emp_start_date,
  coalesce(emp_term_date,
    lead(emp_term_date)
      over (partition by eeid order by coalesce(emp_term_date, emp_start_date)))
    as emp_term_date
from your_table
order by eeid, emp_start_date, orig_start_date, emp_term_date, orig_term_date;

      EEID ORIG_START_DATE ORIG_TERM_DATE EMP_START_DATE EMP_TERM_DATE
---------- --------------- -------------- -------------- -------------
         1 2014-01-01                     2014-01-01     2014-03-30   
         1                 2014-03-30     2014-01-01     2014-03-30   
         1 2014-06-01                     2014-06-01     2014-12-31   
         1                 2014-12-31     2014-06-01     2014-12-31   
         1 2015-08-01                     2015-08-01                  
         2 2001-07-01                     2001-07-01                  
         3 2010-03-01                     2010-03-01     2010-03-30   
         3                 2010-03-30     2010-03-01     2010-03-30   
         3 2010-04-01                     2010-04-01     2010-04-30   
         3                 2010-04-30     2010-04-01     2010-04-30
```

and then eliminate duplicates:

```
select distinct eeid,
  coalesce(emp_start_date,
    lag(emp_start_date)
      over (partition by eeid order by coalesce(emp_start_date, emp_term_date)))
    as emp_start_date,
  coalesce(emp_term_date,
    lead(emp_term_date)
      over (partition by eeid order by coalesce(emp_term_date, emp_start_date)))
    as emp_term_date
from your_table
order by eeid, emp_start_date;

      EEID EMP_START_DATE EMP_TERM_DATE
---------- -------------- -------------
         1 2014-01-01     2014-03-30   
         1 2014-06-01     2014-12-31   
         1 2015-08-01                  
         2 2001-07-01                  
         3 2010-03-01     2010-03-30   
         3 2010-04-01     2010-04-30
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Have marked correct the first answer. Up voted yours. Appreciated!